# Why can't I get and write a token?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to do authentication in the application, but I ran into a problem that the incoming token is not recorded, I'm trying to stuff the incoming token into SharedPreferences.
A variable for storing data and a function that allows you to write data.

```
var prefUserToken:SharedPreferences?=null
fun saveUserToken(res:String){
    val editor = prefUserToken?.edit()
    editor?.putString("UserToken", res)
    editor?.apply()
}
```

Initialization in MainActivity

```
prefUserToken=getSharedPreferences("UserToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Models for authentication request and token receipt

```
data class AuthUser(
    val password:String,
    val username:String,
)
data class UserToken(
    val userToken: String
)
```

API Requests

```
interface StockApi {
    @POST("Coffee/auth/users/")
    suspend fun registrationUser(@Body registrationUser: RegistrationUser):Response<ResponseRegistrationUser>

    @POST("auth/token/login/")
    suspend fun authUser(@Body authUser: AuthUser): Response<UserToken>
}
```

Repository

```
class UserRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val userService: StockApi
): BaseApiResponse() {
    suspend fun registrationUser(user: RegistrationUser): Resource<ResponseRegistrationUser>{
        return safeApiCall { userService.registrationUser(user) }
    }

    suspend fun authenticationUser(user: AuthUser):Resource<UserToken>{
        return safeApiCall { userService.authUser(user) }
    }

}
```

UseCase

```
class AuthUserUserCase @Inject constructor(
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) {
    suspend fun invoke(user: AuthUser)=userRepository.authenticationUser(user=user)
}
```

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class AuthenticationUserViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authUserUserCase: AuthUserUserCase
): ViewModel()  {
    private val _userToken = MutableLiveData<Resource<UserToken>>()
    val userToken:LiveData<Resource<UserToken>>
        get() = _userToken

    fun authUser(user: AuthUser){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            authUserUserCase.invoke(user = user).let {
                _userToken.value=it
            }
        }
    }

}
```

initializing the ViewModel

```
val authenticationUserViewModel= hiltViewModel<AuthenticationUserViewModel>()
val token=authenticationUserViewModel.userToken.observeAsState().value?.data
```

attempt to write a token

```
authenticationUserViewModel.authUser(AuthUser("Serg!@#$", "Serg"))
Thread.sleep(7000)
Log.d("User", token.toString())
if (token != null) {
                    saveUserToken(token.userToken)
} else{
                    saveUserToken("пусто")
}
navController.navigate(Graph.HOME)
```

in Log outputs

```
2023-05-13 09:55:10.799 9138-9138/ru.example.coffeekotlin D/User: null
```

and the most interesting thing is that I get the token in the terminal using OkHttp

```
I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: {"auth_token":"7e0e72e274bbda5e6f3cc9e3563f8c41384a37af"}
```

It seems like the correct data type (`UserToken`) is passed through all levels of the application, and even a token is output in the console, but for some reason the token is not passed to the public variable `ViewModel`.

Comment: It seems that the issue lies in the usage of `observeAsState()` in your code. The `observeAsState()` function returns a State object that holds the latest value emitted by the `LiveData`. However, since you are accessing the value immediately after observing it, it might not have been updated yet.

Comment: @Lrrr and then how to update it correctly? –

Comment: you can observe the `LiveData` using the `observe()` function and perform the token saving logic inside the observer callback.

Comment: Instead of doing `var prefUserToken:SharedPreferences?=null` and then initializing it in the main activity, it would be cleaner just to do `val prefUserToken:SharedPreferences by lazy{prefUserToken=getSharedPreferences("UserToken", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)}`, that way it's not nullable so you can use `.` instead of `?.`.